# I can't add data to the list in flutter bloc. When i add the data, it gets an error

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

i want to add hashtags to the list in state, but i can't add value to list using Bloc Flutter

When i add the data to the list in file bloc, it doesn't work.

Here i send the event by onPressed method.

```
TextButton(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Save',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2?.copyWith(
        fontSize: 15, color: colorBlue, letterSpacing: 1),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    if (_hashtagController.value.text.isNotEmpty) {
        context
            .read<DealsBloc>()
            .add(AddHashtag(hashtag: _hashtagController.value.text));
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  },
),
```

## Event File

Here i describe the event "Add Hashtag".

```
part of 'deals_bloc.dart';

abstract class DealsEvent extends Equatable {

  const DealsEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AddHashtag extends DealsEvent {

  final String hashtag;

  const AddHashtag({
    required this.hashtag
});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [ hashtag ];
}
```

## State File

```
part of 'deals_bloc.dart';

class DealsState extends Equatable {
  final List<String> hashtags;
  final List<Deal> deals;
  final List<String> imagePaths;

  const DealsState({
    this.deals = const <Deal>[],
    this.imagePaths = const <String>[],
    this.hashtags = const <String>['Add a new hashtag']
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [hashtags, deals, imagePaths];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'hashtags': this.hashtags,
      'deals': this.deals,
      'imagePaths': this.imagePaths,
    };
  }

  factory DealsState.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return DealsState(
      hashtags: map['hashtags'] as List<String>,
      deals: map['deals'] as List<Deal>,
      imagePaths: map['imagePaths'] as List<String>,
    );
  }

}
```

## Bloc File

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:trade_stat/blocs/bloc_exports.dart';

part 'deals_event.dart';
part 'deals_state.dart';

class DealsBloc extends HydratedBloc<DealsEvent, DealsState> {
  final DealsRepository dealsRepository;

  DealsBloc({required this.dealsRepository}) : super(const DealsState()) {
    on<AddHashtag>(_onAddHashtag);
  }

void _onAddHashtag(AddHashtag event, Emitter<DealsState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    List<String> hashtags  = state.hashtags;
    hashtags.add(event.hashtag);
    emit(DealsState(hashtags: hashtags));
    print(state.hashtags);
  }

  @override
  DealsState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DealsState.fromMap(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(DealsState state) {
    return state.toMap();
  }

}
```

I try to add the data to the list, but it doesn't work.
When I add data to the list I get an error.

```
E/flutter (10932): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you could do:

```
    List<String> hashtags  = List.from(state.hashtags);
    hashtags.add(event.hashtag);
```

or

Remove const from DealerState

```
const DealsState({
    this.deals,
    this.imagePaths,
    this.hashtags,
  });
```

Comment: I did like you said, but data is not added - I/flutter (10932): [Add a new hashtag]